# "motivation" tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

I find posts requesting "motivation" for various topics to be particularly interesting and useful, and I noted how underused the "motivation" tag is.

I was going to look for motivational posts with the most hits and add the tag, but I thought I should make sure this is OK. I'm not suggesting *every* motivational question should be tagged, but at least the most popular, and the nice ones (like motivation for flatness, Lie algebra etc).

Comment: If you just search "motivat*" and select the "votes" tab you get a pretty good sample of what could be tagged.

Comment: Sounds fine to me.  It's nice that retagging (apparently?) no longer bumps a question back onto the main page.

Comment: @Nate: Really?? OP: There is a closely related,imho, tag [intuition]. While not quite the same I think it is the same driving force under the hood of most motivation and intuition questions. Perhaps we can merge-rename.

Comment: I see, I didn't know about the intuition tag. I've just started editing here and am still on a learning curve. Should I wait a little longer before tagging stuff?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Well, I tried it on one of the sandbox questions here on meta, and it didn't bump it.  You should click the "edit tags" link that appears when you hover over the existing tags on the question's main page, rather than clicking the "edit" button.

Comment: @Nate are you sure? Note that the edit bumps sometimes occur after a slight time-delay: the question you edited may not have been bumped to the front page within one or two minutes.

Comment: @WillieWong: You and Asaf are right and I was mistaken.  Retagging does still bump, unfortunately.